# Is it possible to build the text of a push notification on android devices?

Tags: android, kotlin

I would like to send down a push notification to some android devices from the backend with an arbitrary JSON payload using SNS. I would like the devices to diff the payload against some local device state to produce a specific notification message about what changed and if nothing changed to not show a notification. Is this possible?

Comment: You may have better luck splitting this into separate Android and iOS questions.  Asking about both means that someone who knows the answer on one or the other may not answer your question, when they would otherwise have been able to help you.

Comment: Thanks @RyanM good suggestion will do that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use silent pushes. With the silent push, you can deliver your payload and the applications will have to show a local notification if the state checks out. There are some limitations like if the user force quits the application, silent pushes won't be delivered.

Comment: Is silent push iOS or Android? Does the user have to have the app open?

Comment: On android, by default, the application needs to show the notification so its is "silent" by default, you can create your logic when you receive the push and may decide to not show if needed.

On iOS, all pushes are showed by the system except silent pushes. If the application is running or in the background, the push is received and the app can show a local notification. If the app is not running, the OS might decide not to launch the application so it is not as reliable.